# Access to SAP RSPCM_WEB transaction from outside

Tags: android, ios, saprfc, sap-bw

I'd like to write a mobile app for process chain monitoring. I know the RSPCM_WEB transaction, but we need some more functionality.

Is it possible to access built-in SAP functions like activating a DSO by given name or start other process chains from outside?

I have found the ["SAP Communication between ABAP and Non-ABAP Technologies"](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/641ea1bdbc51eee10000000a421937/content.htm?frameset=/en/48/89653184b84e6fe10000000a421937/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/b4/3f9e64bff38c4f9a19635f57eb4248/plain.htm&node_id=439&show_children=false) where various ways are described. Do I really need to build a function module for each function I had like to access? Is it even possible for all functions?

What about access permissions? Is there any autentification mechanism for that?

Comment: Each of your questions would require a rather extensive explanation, considering that you give very little information about the actual requirements, existing knowledge and steps you've already taken. I doubt that stack overflow is the right format for a discussion like that.

Comment: Sorry if i do not provided enough informations. In short: I would like to write an mobile application just like the RSPCM_WEB transaction in SAP 7.4 with some additional features. One of this features is the possibility to activate an DSO-Object directly in the mobile application (perhaps if the error log in the proccess chain says it wasn't active). Maybe you have some hints for literature?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to access SAP functions. The most simple is to make Web-services wrappers for transactions. But maybe you not to invent a wheel and try set up [Fiori](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-53180)?)) It has built-in mobile client.